# Getting the line number of executing code in TCL

Tags: tcl

how to print the line number of executing TCL script?

```
#! /usr/bin/tclsh

set a "100"
set b "200"
set c [expr $a + $b]
puts [info script] ;# it will display the script name which it is executing. 
                    # similarly I need to print the script line number.
puts $c
```

Comment: I'm not sure why would you want that? You might look into how Tcl throws errors since it also says the line number in which the error occurs in the code.

Comment: There might not be a line number, e.g. if you dynamically created a proc.

Answer (score 8):

You have to use `info frame` to get this done simply.

```
info frame ?number?
```

This command provides access to all frames on the stack, even those hidden from info level. **If number is not specified, this command returns a number giving the frame level of the command.** This is 1 if the command is invoked at top-level. **If number is specified, then the result is a dictionary containing the location information for the command at the numbered level on the stack.**

If number is positive (> 0) then it selects a particular stack level (1 refers to the top-most active command, i.e., `info frame` itself, 2 to the command it was called from, and so on); otherwise it gives a level relative to the current command (0 refers to the current command, i.e., info frame itself, -1 to its caller, and so on).

We are going to make use of the dictionary returned by the `info frame` command. **One of the key is 'line' which contains the line number of the script.**

Have a simple `proc` as,

```
proc printLine {frame_info} {
    # Getting value of the key 'line' from the dictionary 
    # returned by 'info frame'
    set result [dict get [info frame $frame_info]  line] 
}
```

In general, the resulting dictionary from `[info frame $frame_info]` will be something like,

`type source line 17 file /home/dinesh/stackoverflow/test cmd {printLine [info frame] } proc ::B level 1`

From this, we are just getting the key value 'line' with `dict get`

Just call this proc with the current frame number of that context which can be achieved with `info frame` itself.

i.e.

```
set lineNumber [printLine [info frame]]; #Place this line in your code.
```

A demonstration of this logic is as below.

**printLineNumber.tcl**

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
proc printLine {frame_info} {
        # Getting value of the key 'line' from the dictionary 
        # returned by 'info frame'
        set result [dict get [info frame $frame_info]  line]
}
proc D {} {
        puts "proc D"
        puts [ printLine [info frame] ]
}
proc C {} {
        puts "proc C"
        puts [ printLine [info frame] ]
        D
}
proc B {} {
        puts "proc B"
        puts [ printLine [info frame] ]
        C
}
proc A {} {
        puts "proc A"
        puts [ printLine [info frame] ]
        B
}

puts "Global"
puts [ printLine [info frame] ]
A
```

Documentation : [info](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/info.htm#M12), [dict](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm#M13)

Comment: `info frame` isn't required to tell you the line number relative to the file; in some cases, that information is just not available. It does quite a good job though. (Now, if only we used that information for error messages as well…)

Comment: As far as I understand this works started from tcl8.5. Do you know how to get line number in tcl 8.4 ? (it doesn't support info frame)

Comment: @ArmanHunanyan : Unfortunately, this can be done from the `Tcl` 8.5 onwards only.

Comment: Regarding: "1 refers to the top-most active command, i.e., info frame itself, 2 to the command it was called from, and so on", `man n info` says the opposite: "1 refers to the outer-most active command, 2 to the  command  it  called, and so on, up to the current frame level which refers to info frame itself". Your paragraph seems very similar in sentence structure to the paragraph in the manpage, which leads me to believe that you got it from there, but it changed? I wonder if the behaviour changed or if it was just a documentation bug that got fixed.

Comment: I tried this on Tcl 8.6 and it returns 28, 3, 3, 3, 3. If we consider the first line to be 0, then the 28 is correct for the call to procedure A. Unfortunately, the remaining calls of B, C, and D seem to return something that isn't the line number of the caller. I thought they might be relative to the procedure definition, but adding two additional lines to procedure B before the call to C only changes the output to 30, 3, 3, 3, 3.