# Is there any way to find out line number from TCL_interpreter

Tags: tcl

I am trying to implement couple of Tcl commmands in c++.

```
static __tcl_command_t __tcl_command_list[] = {
    {"reset_clock_declaration", 0 ,ZBCU::resetClockDeclaration, 0, "reset clock declaration"},
    {"clock_declaration",       0, ZBCU::recognizeNotClocks,    0, "populate clock declarations"}
};

auto a_command = &__tcl_command_list[index];
Tcl_CreateCommand(interp, a_command->command_name, a_command->command_func,
        (ClientData) this, (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *) nullptr);

// ...

static int
recognizeNotClocks(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, int argc, const char **argv)
{
    // ...
}
```

Inside `recognizeNotClocks()` function I want to know which line number is being processed. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27837009/60725 ?

Comment: Do you mean the line calling your command? Do you mean the script- or file-relative line number?

Comment: Yes, I need the line number calling my command.
e.g.
I have a tcl file a.tcl
clock_declaration <> .......
In the callback, I want to fetch filename = a.tcl and line number = 1

Comment: @schlenk - not useful for my requirement

Answer (score 0):

The caller's line number isn't particularly easy to obtain (it's not information that Tcl really exposes much), but you could try (assuming a recent enough Tcl; without `info frame` you're stuck):

```
int line = -1; // A dummy value
if (Tcl_Eval(interp, "dict get [info frame -1] line") == TCL_OK)
    // The nullptr below because we're ignoring errors
    (void) Tcl_GetIntFromObj(nullptr, Tcl_GetObjResult(interp), &line);
// if line is at least 1, you've got a valid line number.
```

You might need to adjust the value passed to `info frame` (-1 means “caller” but I'm not sure how the call through the C/C++ layer interacts with this).

Note that you could also do the dictionary extraction in C code; this would mean you could pick up other useful mappings in the dict such as `file` and perhaps `proc`. They're not guaranteed to be there (the `proc` key is only present for procedures, and the conditions on when the `file` key is present are very tricky to characterise except to say that it's almost always there for sourced code), but they help debugging a lot.

Note that the information reported by `info frame` is not exported via any public C API of Tcl. You really do have to run a (tiny) script to get it.

---

Be aware that it is considered ***EXTREMELY BAD STYLE*** to make your code vary significantly in behaviour depending on where it is called from or how it is called. It is also the sort of thing that would make your code extremely difficult to debug and test. Have great care!